# Why can't I get the text out of a QTableWidget cell?

Tags: qt, cell, qtablewidget

I have searched the answer, and `ui->tableWidget->item( row, col )->text();` seems to be the answer.
Now, in my code I have:

```
ui-> tableWidget->setItem(row-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("clicked"));
```

This works just fine. When the cell is clicked, it displays the "clicked" message. BUT, when i add this below:

```
QString str;
QTableWidgetItem * itm = ui->tableWidget->item( 3, 1 );
str = itm->text();
```

The program crashes.
Any idea how could I view the text from the cell?

All the code.Constructor:

```
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
    QString dateString = date.toString();

    QFont myFont;
    QFontMetrics font_meter(myFont);
    int line_width=0;

    ui->label->setText(dateString);

    QFile file(":/input.txt");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    QStringList headerLabels;
    QStringList rowLabels;
    QStringList rowContents;


    headerLabels << "Tasks to do" ;

    int row_count=0;

    while (true)
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();

        if (line.isNull())
        {
          file.close();
          break;
        }
        else
        {
            row_count++;
            rowLabels.append(QString("%1").arg(row_count));
            rowContents.append(line);
            if( font_meter.width(line)>line_width)
            {
                line_width=font_meter.width(line);
            }
        }

    }


   ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(row_count);
   ui->tableWidget->setVerticalHeaderLabels(rowLabels);
   ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);

  // ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget();

  for(int i=0;i<row_count;i++)
  {
      ui-> tableWidget->setItem(i-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(rowContents.at(i)));


  }


}
```

slot:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellDoubleClicked(int row, int column)
{

    ui->pushButton->setText( QString("%1").arg(row));

    ui-> tableWidget->setItem(row-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("clicked"));

    QString str;
    QTableWidgetItem * itm = ui->tableWidget->item( 3, 1 );
    str = itm->text();


}
```

I have tried to make another program.Just with a simple table and getting the text out of a cell:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->tableWidget->setItem(1,1,new QTableWidgetItem("lol"));

    QString str= ui->tableWidget->item(1,1)->text();
```

.Exactly the same error

Comment: Could you please share much more code and backtrace for starter?

Comment: Are you sure that `ui->tableWidget->item(...)` returns valid item? It will return 0 if there is no item on specified row and column. Calling `itm->text()` on null item would cause segfault.

Answer (score 2):

```
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(1);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Hello World!"));
QTableWidgetItem *temp = ui->tableWidget->item(0, 0);
QString str = temp->text();
```

Works for me, I only managed to **crash the program when rowCount or columntCount were 0**.